# Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Есть приложение на python + selenium, мне нужно проверить, есть-ли на странице объект с классом #messageBoxInLine
При успешной проверке никаких проблем не возникает, но если объекта на странице нет, приложение просто зависает

```
def msgbox():
  try:
    msgbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#messageBoxInline').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    msgbox_none = 'Таблички нет'
    return msgbox_none
return msgbox
```

Comment: Давайте вопросу заголовок, отражающий суть проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Делай break после сообщения, если ничего не планируешь дальше выполнять:

```
def msgbox():
    try:
        msgbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#messageBoxInline').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        msgbox_none = 'Таблички нет'
        break
return msgbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы объявили переменную, записали в нее текст, но что с ней делать не сказали, вот и он висит, а чтобы не вис никогда, ставьте таймаут с помощью библиотек:

> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
>
> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Ну а Ваш код должен выглядеть с условием так:

```
   def msgbox():
      try:
        if browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#messageBoxInline').text == 'нужный текст':
            return 'True'
      except NoSuchElementException:
           return 'Таблички нет'
```